# Elasticsearch aggregations on nested inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I got a large amount of data in Elasticsearch. My douments have a nested field called "records" that contains a list of objects with several fields.

I want to be able to query specific objects from the records list, and therefore I use the inner_hits field in my query, but It doesn't help because aggregation uses size 0 so no results are returned.

I didn't succeed to make an aggregation work only for inner_hits, as aggregation returns results for all the objects inside records no matter the query.

This is the query I am using:
(Each document has first_timestamp and last_timestamp fields, and each object in the records list has a timestamp field)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_msearch?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'    
{
    "index":[
        "my_index"
    ],
    "search_type":"count",
    "ignore_unavailable":true
}
{
    "size":0,
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
             "query":{
                 "nested":{
                     "path":"records",
                     "query":{
                         "term":{
                             "records.data.field1":"value1"
                         }
                     },
                     "inner_hits":{}
                 }
             },
             "filter":{
                 "bool":{
                     "must":[
                     {
                         "range":{
                             "first_timestamp":{
                                 "gte":1504548296273,
                                 "lte":1504549196273,
                                 "format":"epoch_millis"
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     ],
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     "aggs":{
         "nested_2":{
             "nested":{
                 "path":"records"
             },
             "aggs":{
                 "2":{
                     "date_histogram":{
                          "field":"records.timestamp",
                          "interval":"1s",
                          "min_doc_count":1,
                          "extended_bounds":{
                              "min":1504548296273,
                              "max":1504549196273
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: I find funny that the "modern" JSON syntax replaced the "old school"  SQL in querying data. Well, writing such JSONs sucks. In SQL, you are looking at one JOIN and one GROUP BY. There is a different underlying technology in ElasticSearch, but sorry, ElasticSearch can be close to minus infinity at the topic "Easy to use".

Comment: I'm absolutely with you from the readability point of view.The advantage is the easier composability when creating queries with other programs. That's just assembling data structures in contrast to following syntax rules of a language like SQL.

Comment: I find it is often possible to compact the JSON queries into a single line, without sacrificing readability. For example `{bool: {must: {term: {public: true}}`.

Comment: Well, instead of JSON usually some elastic search builder is used. E.g.  https://elastic-builder.js.org/ And then complexity is not a problem

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your query is pretty complex.
To be short, here is your requested query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "nested_A": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "records"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bool_aggregation_A": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "records.data.field1": "value1"
                  }    
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "reverse_aggregation": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggregations": {
                "bool_aggregation_B": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "first_timestamp": {
                              "gte": 1504548296273,
                              "lte": 1504549196273,
                              "format": "epoch_millis"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                    "nested_B": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "records"
                      },
                      "aggregations": {
                        "my_histogram": {
                          "date_histogram": {
                            "field": "records.timestamp",
                            "interval": "1s",
                            "min_doc_count": 1,
                            "extended_bounds": {
                              "min": 1504548296273,
                              "max": 1504549196273
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, let me explain every step by aggregations' names:

- size: 0 -> we are not interested in hits, only aggregations
- nested_A -> `data.field1` is under records so we dive our scope to records
- bool_aggregation_A -> filter by `data.field1`: value1
- reverse_aggregation -> `first_timestamp` is not in nested document, we need to scope out from records
- bool_aggregation_B -> filter by `first_timestamp` range
- nested_B -> now, we scope again into records for `timestamp` field (located under records)
- my_histogram -> finally, aggregate date histogram by `timestamp` field

Comment: beautiful! This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: This was the first example of using a query within the aggregation filter I've seen.  Thank you for showing how this is done.  Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

Inner_hits aggregation is not supported by elasticsearch. The reason behind it is that inner_hits is a very expensive operation and applying aggregation on inner_hits is like exponential increase in complexity of operation.
[Here is the github link of the issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17376).

If you want aggregation on inner_hits you can probably use the following approach:

1. Make flexible query where you only get the required hit from elastic and aggregate over it. Repeat it multiple time to get all the hits and aggregate simultaneously. This approach may lead you with multiple search query which is not advisable.
2. You can make your application layer handle the aggregation logic by writing smart aggregation parser and run those parser on response from elasticsearch. This approach is a little better but you have an overhead of maintaining the parser according to changing needs.

I would personally recommend you to change your data-mapping style in elasticsearch so that you are able to run aggregation on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the code like this

```
PUT records
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "records": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST records/_doc
{
  "records": [
    {
      "data": "test1",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "data": "test2",
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}

GET records/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all_nested_count": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "records"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bool_aggs": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "records.data": "test2"
                  }    
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_aggs": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "records.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html

[image]